# C++11 Create compile time boolean expression with variadic template arguments

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates

Let say i have following base struct

```
struct Functor
{
    virtual bool execute()=0;
};
```

On which base i created structs A, B and C.
Now i want to evaluate boolean expression on variadic list of these objects which i would at runtime do like this:

```
bool evaluate(list<Functor> objs)
{
    for(list<Functor>::iterator it = objs.begin(); it!=objs.end();++it)
    {
        if(!it->execute())
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

My question is can i by having function declared like this

```
template<typename ...F>
static bool doEvaluation(F... args)
{
    return... args->execute();
}
```

And executing it like this

```
doEvaluation(new A(), new B(), new C());
```

In the end get something like this at compile time?

```
return new A()->execute() && new B()->execute() && new C()->execute();
```

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but using `new` here is probably the wrong thing to do as you would have memory leaks.

Comment: Yes. I did that only to make things shorter to write

Comment: Your `list<Functor>` is subject to slicing, so you probably couldn't implement it that way, anyway.

Comment: `A().execute()` would be "shorter to write" _and_ not be wrong :)

Comment: As for your problem, you need *two* `doEvaluation` functions, of which one calls itself recursively. There are many example of it for parameter packs. Then you can can make them `constexpr` which should solve your compile-time requirement, with a small caveat: The `execute` function is itself not a `constexpr` function and can not be evaluated at compile-time (the compiler doesn't to virtual function lookup, it's a run-time operation).

Comment: I predict that a future extension of [fold expressions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold) will one day provide a concise syntax for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement something like what you are after, as follows:

```
#include <functional>
// overload for single argument
template <typename T>
constexpr bool check(T&& f) {
    return f();
}

// extract the first parameter then recursively call self for others
template <typename U, typename... T>
constexpr bool check(U&& f, T&&... t) {
    // this will short-circuit...
    return f() && check(std::forward<T>(t)...);
}

template <typename T, bool V>
struct A {
  // this method can be called at compile time
  constexpr bool operator()() const {
      return V;
  }
};

int main()
{
  constexpr auto v1 = check(A<int, true>{}, A<int, false>{}, A<double, true>{});
  static_assert(v1 == false, "expected false!");
  constexpr auto v2 = check(A<int, true>{}, A<int, true>{}, A<double, true>{}, A<float, true>{});
  static_assert(v2, "expected true!");
}
```

I'm sure it's possible to simplify this further. The inheritance stuff is not necessary, and the computation of the flags is done at compile time.

Comment: Thanks that was exactly what i was looking for!